# Why GoogleMap is not showing with key and is showing with v in my .net project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am struck in a problem while using google map in my .net project

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I am using the above code I am properly getting the google map but if I tried to add key

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxx-&libraries=places&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Map is not showing and also getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

I also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxx_xxx---------&libraries=places"></script>
```

But still it is not working.
Any suggesstion?

Comment: Show your code first!

Comment: @binoy show ur initializer and listener functions

Comment: thank you for your comments I just wanted to know the reason for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the "v=3" parameter, it defaults to the experimental version of the API (if you have a standard plan account). It appears that there is a fault with the experimental version that's not displaying a map at the moment. So add the "v=3" parameter in addition to the other parameters.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=<YourAPIKey>&libraries=places&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```